# OAuth in c# get Access token

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to get access token via sending client id and secret key in an example sandbox url. Can someone please help me with a sample code of it in c# ?

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

consumer_key = "utuhfhnxjdjd"
consumer_secret = "99ehdjncnv"
api_URL = "https://example.com/oauth/v1/generate?grant_type=client_credentials"

r = requests.get(api_URL, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(consumer_key, consumer_secret))

print (r.text)
```

Comment: Read up on how to use `HttpClient` in c#

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to setup a class that wraps HTTPClient in order to make a call to a REST WebService using basic authentication:

https://gist.github.com/snafu918/b064624a4d5cd78533e0479680bb35ce

```
    public class XyzServiceClient
    {
        internal static HttpClient Client { get; set; } = new HttpClient();
        private readonly string _uri;


        public XyzServiceClient(string apiUrl)
        {
            _uri = apiUrl;
            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        }

        public Xyz CallService(string username, string password)
        {
            var result = new Xyz();
            HttpResponseMessage response = CallXyzService(username, password);
            return ParseResponse(response, result);
        }

        internal HttpResponseMessage CallXyzService(string username, string password)
        {
            return Client.SendAsync(CreateHttpRequestMessage(username, password)).Result;
        }

        internal HttpRequestMessage CreateHttpRequestMessage(string username, string password)
        {
            var msg = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, _uri);
            var authByteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{username}:{password}");
            msg.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(authByteArray));
            return msg;
        }

        internal Xyz ParseResponse(HttpResponseMessage response, Xyz result)
        {
            if (response == null || !response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                throw new Exception("Response from service indicates failure.");
            }

            using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
            {
                string contentResult = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                // do something to create your Xyz object using data in 
                //contentResult

             }
             return xyzResult;
            }
        }
```

Comment: what is Xyz as you used here ?

Comment: An object that you would build to match the payload that you're getting back in the body of the response. Normally if you're getting json back you'd create a C# object to represent that same structure and then deserialize the data from json into c# objects that you can then work with.